# Converting string containing nan to a numpy float array

Tags: python, numpy

I have strings like these

```
'[15, 8.0, 5.0, 5.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]'
'[8, 6.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]'
```

Which I would like to convert to Numpy arrays of floats. Is there an easy conversion function?

I have tried `json.loads`, but that seems to fail at the `NaN`s even if I string replace them with `np.nan`. I have tried stripping off the brackets and using numpy's from string but that fails too.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
from numpy import nan, array
a = '[15, 8.0, 5.0, 5.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]'
arr = array(eval(a))
```

This brings `nan` into the namescape and then evaluates `a` as a Python expression. The result is a list that can be readily converted into a numpy array.

Be aware that using `eval` is risky if your strings come from an untrusted source (such as user input), since it may lead to arbitrary code execution. A safer version would be:

```
import ast
import numpy as np

def convert(s):
    # replace the nan values so that ast.literal_eval() can interpret them
    s = s.replace('nan', 'None')
    # safely evaluate s as Python expression
    l = ast.literal_eval(s)
    # replace the Nones back to np.nans
    l = [x if x is not None else np.nan for x in l]
    return np.array(l)
```

Then:

```
a = '[15, 8.0, 5.0, 5.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]'
convert(a)
```

returns

```
array([15.,  8.,  5.,  5., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])
```